# Which values to update to in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat, android-sdk-manager

[image: SDK Manager]

[image: Part 2]

This is what my sdk manager currently looks like.In the build.gradle file what changes would i have to make so that i am up to date.
My current compilesdkversion is 23 and buildsdkversion is 23.0.1.
All the com.android.support.* libraries are on 23.1.0.

Comment: Your build.gradle file is just updated. The SDK Tools is not defined in buidl.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `build.gradle` file is updated.

> My current compilesdkversion is 23 and buildsdkversion is 23.0.1. All the com.android.support.* libraries are on 23.1.0.

```
compilesdkversion 23  -->ANDROID API 23

buildsdkversion 23.0.1 --> Android SDK Build-Tools

com.android.support.xxx  23.1.0  -->Android Support Repositories/Android Support Library
```

The **Android SDK Tools** is not in your `build.gradle`
SDK Tools is a downloadable component for the Android SDK. It includes the complete set of development and debugging tools for the Android SDK.

More [info here:](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html)

```
 SDK Tools, Revision 24.4.1 (October 2015)

  Dependencies:
    Android SDK Platform-tools revision 23 or later.

  General Notes:
    Fixed a problem where the emulator title bar was hidden off screen. (Issue 178344)
    Enabled the emulator to resize the user data partition by including e2fsprogs binaries. (Issue 189030)
    Fixed a regression on the 32-bit Windows OS where the emulator fails to boot Android 6.0 (API level 23) through Android 5.0 (API level 21) system images. (Issue 188326)

  SDK Tools, Revision 24.4.0 (October 2015)

  Dependencies:
    Android SDK Platform-tools revision 23 or later.

  General Notes:
    Updated the emulator so it can display an upgrade notification when a new version is available.
    Added the ability for the emulator to send basic crash reports. You must opt-in through Android Studio preferences to enable crash report transmission.
```

Answer (score 1):

None. Neither the SDK or the build tools are updated, only the SDK Tools.

Comment: So if i were to update to 24.4.1 i would not have to make any changes in my gradle file?